# How to run a macro from button in custom ribbon ?

Tags: vb.net, excel, macros, excel-2007

I created a custom ribbon using **Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabHome" >
        <group id="customGroup1" label="My Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditingExcel">
          <button id="customButton1" label="Click Me" size="large" onAction="test()" imageMso="HappyFace" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I saved excel 2007 file as **Excel Macro-Enabled workbook**

Here is my macro. It works fine when it run manually

```
Sub test()
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To i
    Cells(i, j) = j
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

But When I press the smiling face button in my custom ribbon it gives following error message.

> cannot run the macro 'test()' the macro may not be available in this
>   workbook or all macro may be disabled.

**How can I fix this issue ? Any suggestions ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should not include the brackets. So change this:

onAction="test()"

to:

onAction="test"

Also, make sure the routine name is unique and does not exist in any other workbook you might have open in Excel, otherwise you risk the wrong routine being called.